# Generalized anxiety disorder and reasonable interview process accommodations

Tags: interviewing, software-industry, united-states, disability

I have generalized anxiety disorder that involves a number of different symptoms, but what matters here is poor attention and concentration, decreased verbal skills and fatigue when I feel anxious, especially when I'm under stress. The key difference with the linked question on epilepsy is that the mind disturbances due to GAD are less extreme but last for longer, potentially for days or even weeks.

I've been working as a software engineer for quite a few years and have a portfolio of successful projects (nothing grand, though) and recommendations from my previous employers.

I know that ADA requires the employer to provide "reasonable accommodations", but how far this can actually go in my case and what adjustments can I reasonably ask for? (Think of the standard interviewing process that companies like Google and Microsoft use that involves "show me how you're thinking outside the box" tasks, etc. This question is only about the accommodations in the job interview process)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94264/discussion-on-question-by-user855286-generalized-anxiety-disorder-and-reasonable).

Comment: In the three hours since another mod moved comments to chat, *65 more comments* were added, all extended discussions.  Take discussion to chat, please.  And no, I can't easily move those 65 comments into the chat room, so they're gone now.

Answer (score 7):

In a comment you clarified your question as,

> I'm here to know what possible accommodations I can get

This makes for a bit of a chicken and egg situation, since we can't tell you what accommodations you can get until you tell us what accommodations you need. According to the EEOC, **you can essentially get whatever accommodations you need**, in order for you to be fairly evaluated for the job opening. There are some limits - employers are not required to provide accommodations that would cause an undue hardship (i.e. things that were very expensive or time-consuming to the point that it would be destructive to the job search process).

Keep in mind that in some cases, **a disability may legitimately prevent you from carrying out specific job duties, in which case an employer can legitimately refuse to provide accommodations.** For instance, imagine if an employer has a job opening that requires the ability to read, and they include a written test during the interview process. Further, imagine that a candidate claimed they needed an oral test because of dyslexia. **The employer can refuse on the grounds that the job requires the ability to read.** This may be relevant to your specific disability, since employers may make a legitimate case that some of the things you're describing would prevent you from reasonably performing the job (i.e. the ability to concentrate and focus your attention when stressed).

Reference: https://www.eeoc.gov/facts/jobapplicant.html

Comment: I didn't mention dyslexia at all, and I don't have it. Ok, let me come up with an example. The company says that they can't hire a guy who is a wheelchair user, because they do stand-up meetings and this is an absolutely essential requirement for the job. Is this a legitimate case?

Comment: +1 for the link alone.

Comment: Shame the comment is no longer available...

Comment: @user855286 if you didn't like my generic dyslexia example, I'm not sure what value your wheelchair example will have. The point of the answer is, you need to decide what accommodations you need. If you can provide some real, concrete examples, you may get a more meaningful response. Otherwise, all we can do is describe the general requirements per the EEOC.

Comment: @SolarMike - I edited the same link into my answer here since it was removed as part of the comments sweep (which seemed legitimate, the comments on the question were getting long!)

Comment: My understanding from my training is that the rules on accommodations are *deliberately* left vague because every case is different. The candidate gets to ask for something that works for them rather than having to fit a previous definition.

Comment: You wrote that I claimed it. Probably "if" is missing.

Comment: @user855286 - I had assumed that "for instance," and "imagine" had made it clear that the sentences that followed was a made up scenario for the sake of example. I will edit to make that more clear.

Comment: You've just edited your answer, "imagine" wasn't present in the original form.

Comment: So now we clarified this, can you answer to my question about the wheelchair user?

Comment: @user855286 - Go ahead and look at the edit history if you'd like. There are now two "imagines." The first one was there in the first version. I just added the second one.

Comment: Well ok, I probably misread it. Now you can answer to my question?

Comment: An employer is allowed to interview based on the skills needed to perform a job's duties, and they're allowed to refuse interview accommodations that side-step those skills or reject candidates who cannot perform duties with reasonable accommodations. Your wheelchair scenario seems deliberately facetious, it doesn't seem reasonable that an employer could literally *require* employees to stand at a "stand up" meeting - the reasonable accommodation in that case would be to have the employee remain in their wheelchair.

Answer (score -3):

If they have to do something for your interview, wouldn't that tell them that they'd need to do something if they hired you?  If someone came into the factory wearing a back brace I don't think they'd get hire.

That's just telling them not to hire you.